# How to make round walls with big radius

Tags: laminating, round

I'm trying to think of a good way to make this:

[image]

But the round sides with the massive radius stumble me. The only way I can think of is cutting many half circles from plywood and then gluing them together to reach the depth of the desired piece. But that seems a bit like an overkill, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Carving it out of the solid didn't appeal? ^_^

Comment: Heh... Turn a cylinder on a (large) lathe, then bisect and extend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Laminate from veneers that are thin enough to bend the radius cold
- Solid wood kerfed on the inside face
- Steam bent solid wood

But my best bet looking at the style of that piece would be many partial circles cut from MDF glued in stacks, sanded, and veneered on the surfaces. Overlapping shorter segments would make more efficient use of the material than full half-circles.

Comment: Totally agree with the stacked glue-up idea.  Note the transitions for round to straight - this was obviously four pieces at one time, joined and then wrap-n-vac'd with veneer.  Nice job on the edgebanding.